# Will ground cover conifers grow branches on a former house side of the plant?

Tags: ground-cover, conifers

I was given a ground cover conifer for free, and accidently planted the side with branches in the wrong direction. Should I replant it, or let it grow out as is?[image: conifer]

Answer (score 3):

If you've only just planted it, dig it up and reposition it if you want, if you think it'll look better that way. It may not grow from the side which currently has no branches anyway. Keep well watered.

Comment: what is your reasoning?

Comment: Regarding what, exactly?

Comment: why would you replant it if it's going to be getting some mulch down eventually also? won't the branches grow on the "bald side"?

Comment: They may not, but if you look, you'll see I said'if you want' to replant, perhaps because it will look more aesthetically pleasing in its current state of lopsided growth. Only you can decide that.

Comment: @Bamboo would you add the reasoning to your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It will look lopsided any way you look at it, since it was growing alongside a house long enough.